# bash extract list file and group them into another file

Tags: bash, extract

I have a file, dynamically populated, containing some dates, one per line, like this:

```
20190807
20190806
20190805
20190804
```

I created a script to read the file line by line, and extract a list of files present into another directory:

```
FILEMASTER="lista_master"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    ls -tr /var/home/test/*_"$line"_*.jpg | head -n2 >> lista_test
done < "$FILEMASTER"
```

This script is ok, creating a single file (lista_test), containing the last two .jpg file for every date.  Output sample:

```
/var/home/test/MAN_20190804_jolly1.jpg
/var/home/test/CAT_20190804_selly2.jpg
/var/home/test/RET_20190805_jolly1.jpg
/var/home/test/GES_20190805_angyt2.jpg
/var/home/test/TOR_20190806_jolly1.jpg
/var/home/test/GIL_20190806_gally2.jpg
/var/home/test/POE_20190807_frity1.jpg
/var/home/test/TAR_20190807_tally2.jpg
```

**My problem is this:**

I should extract different result files )"lista_test1", "lista_test2", "lista_test3", "lista_test4" etc) for every extract line.  NOT all files in a single file.

Comment: Based on what condition lista_test needs to be split into lista_test1, lista_test2, etc.? Should every line of lista_test be extracted to a new file?

Comment: Welcome to SO, I edited your question to make it easier to understand.  Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: just add a counter before the loop. and increment it inside the loop and add the counter in your output file.

Comment: `counter=1; while .....; do .... > "lista_test$counter"; ((counter++)); done < "$file_master"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want one files list per date, reuse the variables in your loop.  Like this:

- Assuming you have a list of dates in a file (named dates_list.txt) like this:

  ```
  20200101
  20200202
  20200303
  20200404
  ```
- Then your script could look like this:

  ```
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
      ls -tr /var/home/test/*_"$line"_*.jpg | head -n2 > $line.list
  done < dates_list.txt
  ```

Note that I would put `>` instead of `>>` to ensure you do not add the same files over and over each time you run the script.

- The result would be:

  ```
  20200101.list        # contain the files *_20200101_*.jpg
  20200202.list        # contain the files *_20200202_*.jpg
  20200303.list        # contain the files *_20200303_*.jpg
  20200404.list        # contain the files *_20200404_*.jpg
  ```

Comment: Hi Nic3500, the script work perfectly! very good, thanks a lot for your support

Comment: With pleasure, I would appreciate if you accepted the answer (checkmark on the left of the answer).